# How to install python packages in virtual environment only with virtualenv bootstrap script?

Tags: python, deployment, virtualenv

I want to create a bootstrap script for setting up a local environment and installing all requirments in it. I have been trying with virtualenv.create_bootstrap_script as described in their [docs](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).

```
import virtualenv
s = virtualenv.create_bootstrap_script('''
import subprocess
def after_install(options, home_dir):
  subprocess.call(['pip', 'install', 'django'])
''')
open('bootstrap.py','w').write(s)
```

When running the resulting bootstrap.py, it sets up the virtual environment correctly, but it then attempts to install Django globally.

How can I write a bootstrap script that installs Django only in this local virtual environment. It has to work on both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You could force pip to install into your virtualenv by:

```
subprocess.call(['pip', 'install', '-E', home_dir, 'django'])
```

Furthermore, it is a nice and useful convention to store your dependencies in requirements.txt file, for django 1.3 that'd be:

```
django==1.3
```

and then in your `after_install`:

```
subprocess.call(['pip', 'install', '-E', home_dir, '-r', path_to_req_txt])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it the fully qualified path to the `pip` script that is in your virtualenv.

`subprocess.call([join(home_dir, 'bin', 'pip'),'install','django'])`

Comment: Thanks. That will not work under Windows, since it would be './Scripts/pip.exe'. Do I really have to make a special case for this?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: I don't think you have to do this, pip's activate augments PATH variable afaik

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works on both Windows and Linux. It uses the pip, just installed by the bootstrap script.

```
import virtualenv
s = '''
import subprocess, os
def after_install(options, home_dir):
  if os.name == 'posix':
    subprocess.call([os.path.join(home_dir, 'bin', 'pip'), 'install', '-r', 'requirements.txt'])
  else:
    subprocess.call([os.path.join(home_dir, 'Scripts', 'pip.exe'), 'install', '-r', 'requirements.txt'])
'''
script = virtualenv.create_bootstrap_script(s, python_version='2.7')
f = open('bootstrap.py','w')
f.write(script)
f.close()
```

Just put your requirements in `requirements.txt`, one line for every package:

```
django
django-registration==1.4.3
```

See: [Pip - Requiremments Files](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html)

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me is to access **pip** from the newly created **environment**.

```
pip = os.path.join(home_dir, 'bin', 'pip')
```

And after that, I try to install **django** as you previously did.

```
subprocess.call([pip, 'install', 'django'])
```

Remember the **os** import:

```
import os, subprocess
```

Hope it works for you.